# Explore contents of Uri Folder retrieved from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I want to be able to access the list of files from a DocumentFile, when the user selects a folder instead of a file. I am calling the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setFlags(FLAG_READ_WRITE|FLAG_PERSIST );
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType(TYPE_ANY);
    String [] mimeTypes = {TYPE_IMAGE,TYPE_VIDEO};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_VIDEOS);
```

(neverming the `FLAG_...` and `TYPE_...` they are what you would expect for their names)
then, in `onActivityResult`:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {               
          if (resultData != null) {
                Uri uri = resultData.getData(); // try to get only one element
                if (uri!=null){ // data is available as ClipData because multiple items were selected
                    Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
                    selectedDocs.add(uri);
                }else{
                    ClipData data = resultData.getClipData();
                    for(int i=0;i<data.getItemCount();i++){
                        ClipData.Item item = data.getItemAt(i);
                        Uri aUri = item.getUri();
                        selectedDocs.add(aUri);
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "handleReadRequestResult: data=" + data.toString());
                }
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "handleReadRequestResult: resultData is null");
                handleIssues();
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "handleReadRequestResult: resultCode is not OK");
            handleIssues();
        }
```

However, when I try to read the uris, there are two cases:
(i) current Uri "is a file", and (ii) curent Uri "is a Folder"

***EDIT: as I have been told, case (ii) is not the default behavior. 
I can reproduce this by longtapping a folder (multiple-selection mode ? ) –***

in case (i), I can do this: `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(),uri)`, and work with the stuff. the problem is in case (ii), where I would like to list available files.

NOTE: when calling `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)`, I get `uri.toString()=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/BEAE-19F8%3AFolderName`, but with `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)`, I get `uri.toString()=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/BEAE-19F8%3AFolderName`.

the difference here is that when the intent is a `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, I can do `DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),uri)`, and then `df.listFiles` (which Will fail for the other case)

Comment: The user cannot select a folder with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. So your problem description is wrong.

Comment: If `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is returning "folders" (i.e., a "document" that really is a document tree), IMHO that's a bug. It should only allow users to select documents, even in multiple-selection mode.

Comment: I can produce this behavior by longtapping a folder (multiple-selection mode ? )

Comment: Please put that info directly in your post. You should have done that right away. I will investigate.

Comment: It is indeed Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE that allows you to select a folder with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. It's just as you said it is. Never seen that before. What to do with it? What can be done with it?

Comment: One can select multiple folders and files then.

Comment: @greenapps yes, but as I mentioned in the NOTE, the intent is ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, so the repective Uri for the folder cant (or at least I dont know how to) be used to `listFiles()`...

Comment: I know that it is action OPEN_DOCUMENT. And as the delivered uri is a wrong one for a folder just dont use it. What is wrong with ACTION_OPEN_DOCEMENT_TREE?

Comment: example: root: {file A1, file A2, dir B};
dir B: {file B1, file B2}

I want the user to be able to select several files at once (hence the `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`), but as on my test I had some files on the root and some other on subfolders, I thought any user could've selected both a file and a folder. Maybe the user does not want all files inside the root folder (eg he wants A1,B1,B2)

Comment: You better ask the user why he selected a folder. You offered him to select a file or multiple files isnt it? Its a bug. Dont build your app on it! It will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ugly, but it seems to do the trick for me ( I dont know the consequences it'll have though):

```
DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(uri.toString().replace("/document/", "/tree/")))
```

no complaints!! I can even do `df.listFiles()` (which is what I wanted all along!)

***EDIT: complain Nº1: persistable uri permissions for that folder are required***

Comment: Can you do this without ever having taken persistable uri permissions for that folder? Or for a parent folder?

Comment: touché! Indeed, persistable uri permission is a requirement. I just tested data clear + uninstalling and re-installing the app, producing DocumentFile which does not exist!

Comment: Ok. Nice to know. So now do not build your app on it!

Comment: Man you are a God ,I staying on this for a whole day .